# Node.js - socket hung up on HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js

Since yesterday i'm struggling with a 'socket hung up error' on the client in node.js (javascript). I have an array with about 1500 image urls that i need to download to a directory. All image urls in the array link to images that are in .png format.

I start by creating a function to download the image by the url. This function looks like this:

```
downloadImageByUrl = (url, filename) => {
    var client = http;
    if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0){
      client = https;
     }
    client.request(url, (response) => {
      var data = new Stream();
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
         data.push(chunk);
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
         fs.writeFileSync(filename, data.read());
      });
   }).end();
};
```

Next i loop over the array that contains the image urls and call the above function:

```
downloadAllImages = (arrayThatContainsImageUrls) => {
  const imageDestination = __dirname + '/img/';
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayThatContainsImageUrls.length; i++) {
    downloadImageByUrl(arrayThatContainsImageUrls[i], iconDestination + i + '.png');
  }
}
```

This all goes well but when there are about 200-300 images downloaded the console throws a socket hung up error:

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1140:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 's1.example.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined }
```

I think it has something to do with the amount of requests that are send at once since it works fine when i only want to download, lets say 10 images. It might also be some async issue but by now im just guessing.

Who can explain me why this is happening and how it can be handled properly? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does it only happen on https connections? Also, have you considered using https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: it could also be that some servers will refuse your connection because you're not a browser

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, but on a single request when the response is too big. For instance, it works fine on a single image of 5MB, the error shows up when the image is 100MB or higher.